# Не работает try except

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, pyrogram

try и except не работают, (это бот на pyrogram для бана всех у кого есть не русские символы в имени)
код:

```
@app.on_message(filters.new_chat_members)
def updated(_, msg):
    with open(white_list_path, "r") as my_file:
        white_list = json.load(my_file)
    msg.delete()
    try:
        name = msg.from_user.first_name
        for i in white_list:
            try:
                if name == i:
                    break
            except:
                if isinstance(message := app.ban_chat_member(chat_id=group_id, user_id=int(msg.from_user.id)), Message):
                    message.delete()
                break
                
        else:
            if name is not None:
                for i in rus_alphabet:
                    for z in msg.from_user.first_name:
                        if i.lower() == z.lower():
                            if msg.from_user.last_name != None:
                                for x in msg.from_user.last_name:
                                    if i.lower() == x.lower():
                                        print(True)
                                        return
                                    else:
                                        if isinstance(message := app.ban_chat_member(chat_id=group_id, user_id=int(msg.from_user.id)), Message):
                                            message.delete()
                                        return
                        else:
                            if isinstance(message := app.ban_chat_member(chat_id=group_id, user_id=int(msg.from_user.id)), Message):
                                message.delete()
                            return

    except:
        if isinstance(message := app.ban_chat_member(chat_id=group_id, user_id=int(msg.from_user.id)), Message):
            message.delete()
        return
```

ошибка:

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 224, in handler_worker
    await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\kolch\Desktop\all\Prog\py\Group_filter\filter_main.py", line 60, in updated
    if isinstance(message := app.ban_chat_member(chat_id=group_id, user_id=int(msg.from_user.id)), Message):
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\sync.py", line 78, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine, main_loop).result()
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 446, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\chats\ban_chat_member.py", line 71, in ban_chat_member
    chat_peer = await self.resolve_peer(chat_id)
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\resolve_peer.py", line 60, in resolve_peer
    return await self.storage.get_peer_by_id(peer_id)
  File "C:\Users\kolch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\storage\sqlite_storage.py", line 141, in get_peer_by_id
    r = self.conn.execute(
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: а где кусок, вызывающий ошибки?  Где это: "if rus_alphabet.index(i.lower()) != None", где list? И откуда вообще идея, что не рабоатют именно try и except? Что на это указывает?

Comment: Для начала заглянуть в учебник по пайтону. Еще раз прочитать про try-except.